# mobX + React can't inject

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I have this question, I look the answer,but can't solve my question.

The error is tips me `'TypeError: Cannot read property 'changeUsername' of undefined'`.

The code is as follows：

```
import {observer, inject} from 'mobx-react';

@inject(['loginStore'])  
@observer
class login extends Component {


    changeUsername = (e) => {
        debugger;
        this.props.loginStore.changeUsername(e.target.value)
    }

    changePassword = (e) => {
        debugger;
        this.props.loginStore.changePassword(e.target.value)
    }



}
```

Comment: can you please show the source code for `loginStore`

Comment: click on the "comment" link below my answer to offer clarification - your use of the `<Provider>` looks correct however I would need to see what is in your 'stores' module, ie `import * as stores from '../stores';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that you have registered store instances with your application. This is done via the `Provider` component (see example below).

The `<Provider>` ensures that the login store can be accessed by nested components in your application - in your case, the login component. Some key concepts to be aware of are:

- A store object must be defined
- A store instance must be registered via the `<Provider/>` (see example below)
- A store can then be accessed by components
- `@inject` can be used to select and inject specific stores into components (ie in cases where a complex application has many stores defined)

This code example hopefully conveys these concepts for you:

```
import {observer, Provider, inject, action } from 'mobx-react';

/*
Define your loginStore
*/
class LoginStore  {
    @action
    changeUsername(value) {
        console.log(value)
    }

    @action
    changePassword(value) {
        console.log(value)
    }
}

@inject('loginStore')
@observer
class login extends Component {

    /* Declare member function in this way, rather than as lambda function */
    changeUsername(e) {
        debugger;
        this.props.loginStore.changeUsername(e.target.value)
    }

    /* Declare member function in this way, rather than as lambda function */
    changePassword(e) {
        debugger;
        this.props.loginStore.changePassword(e.target.value)
    }

    render() {
        return <p>hello world</p>
    }
}

/*
You need to register your store with the provider
*/
const app = (
<Provider loginStore={ new LoginStore() }>
    <login />
</Provider>  
);

ReactDom.render(app, container);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Dacre Denny
Hello,i do not kown how to reply,so i @ you.

I was use the way you say,and id router code use '' follow:

```js
import * as stores from '../stores';

export default class Container extends BasePage{

    render(){
        
        return(
            <Provider { ...stores}>
                <Router>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route path="/login" component={login}/>
                            <Route path="/reg" component={reg}/>
                            <Route path="/404" component={NotFound}/>
                            <Route path="/main" component={mainindex}/>
                            <Route path="/react" component={App}/>
                            <Route component={adminmain}/>
                        </Switch>
                </Router>
            </Provider>
        )
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this router your root component? Usually it's done in index.js.

Answer (score 0):

You inject has the store name in an array. It should just be an argument

`@inject('loginStore')`

Where `loginStore' would be whatever your export is inside of your stores file.